# Why is the dot product of a sine wave with anything a sine of the phase shift?

Tags: inner-products, fourier-transform, correlation

I'm trying to wrap my head around the fact that multiplying anything on a sine wave then calculating the sum of products is a sine of the sine wave's phase.

This is literally the foundation of the Fourier transform, because it allows us to find the maximum of the signal's cross-correlation with a sine wave by sampling it (cross-correlation) in just two points separated by 90 degrees (as opposed to analyzing the whole cross-correlation curve as I do in the following plots).

Intuitively I do understand that this has something to do with the fact that cross-correlation has integration under the hood, and a sine stays a sine after being integrated. But a more illustrative explanation would be nice.

I searched the Web and the only explanations that pop up are *based* on Fourier transform. That won't do.

Poor man's equation:

$(f(t)\star\sin(\omega t))(\tau)=A\sin(\tau+\phi)$

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you formulate your question with math, rather than words or pictures?

Comment: @MathFail I tried

Comment: The equation $(f(t)\star\sin(\omega t))(\tau)=A\sin(\tau+\phi)$ has $f$ and $\omega$ on the left but not on the right, and has $A$ and $\phi$ on the right but not on the left.

Comment: @elemelons not sure what you mean... The point is that the *shape* of the cross-correlation is sinusoidal. Obviously $A$ and $\phi$ on the right side depend on $f$ and $\omega$ on the left. That's what the Fourier transform does - calculate one from the other.

Comment: Again, that's the whole point of the question. Those "infinitely many degrees of freedom" collapse into exactly two, the harmonic wave's amplitude and phase (for given $\omega$, that is).

Comment: I assume that $f \star \sin$ denotes the convolution. If you call $y(\tau )$ the convolution, you can check that $y$ satisfies the differential equation $$y'' = - \omega^2 y$$ whose solution is well known to be a sine or a cosine.

Comment: @Crostul YES! I knew that solution lies in differentiation! Please convert your comment to an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call $$y(\tau) = (f(t) \star \sin (\omega t))(\tau)$$
Then, using differentiation under integral sign you can check that $y$ satisfies the differential equation
$$y'' = - \omega^2 y$$
whose solution is well known to be a sine function.